# How to convert large DMS coordinates into an acceptable format in GIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel, degrees-minutes-seconds

I am trying to add points to a GIS map from a dataset. However, the lat/long coordinates are in the form of six digit DMS degrees. All I would need to do is separate the coordinates into a Degree, Minute, Second Format.

For example,
I would like the latitude 382209.6 to be notated as 38°22'09.6"N or as the equivalent decimal degree if possible.

Would I able to quickly convert all of the coordinates in the dataset to an acceptable format either in the attribute table or Excel?

Comment: Searching on the tag "dms" returned a number of potential duplicates https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/degrees-minutes-seconds?tab=Newest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you explored the [Convert Coordinate Notation tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/convert-coordinate-notation.htm)? This can take as input a table and generate a new Featureclass with the converted coordinates included. You can them simply copy and paste into Excel.

Comment: Thanks, this worked even with the strange formatting.